# spresense拡張ボードを使用してmicroSDカード2枚にデータを保存したい

Tags: spresense, arduino

sony公式ホームページ-spresenseハードウェア設計資料-spresense拡張ボードの回路図を見ての質問です．
拡張ボード裏面（Side-B）cn5の表面実装部にmicroSDコネクタをハンダ付けすることで，microSDカード２枚にデータを保存できるのではないかと考えているのですが可能でしょうか？また，可能な場合はそのサンプルプログラムなどがあれば教えていただきたいです．開発環境はArduino IDEです．

[image: spresense拡張ボードの回路図（一部抜粋）]

Answer (score 1):

[TXS02612のデータシート](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://www.ti.com/jp/lit/ds/symlink/txs02612.pdf?ts=1656055691179&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252Fja-jp%252FTXS02612)を見てみたのですが、TXS02612は２つのインターフェース出力があるようです。一つは、SDカード等のメモリーカードインターフェース、もう一つはWiFi/BT等用のSDIOインターフェースです。どちらのインターフェースを使うかはSELで選択するようになっています。

したがって、２つのSDカードを同時に使えるというわけではないと思います。

SELはSPR_AP_CLK（恐らくGPIOとして使える？）につながっているようなので、SDカード使わずに、WiFiなどを接続したい人は、SPR_AP_CLKの状態を変えれば、CN5を通して通信モジュールを接続することができますよ。という目的で準備されたものだと思います。

[image: TXS02612ブロックダイアグラム]